# How the object gets initialized without 'new' keyword in PageObject approach

Tags: java, selenium, object, inheritance, pageobjects

Can somebody please describe why I can create a new object of Page in Steps class without 'new' keyword? It's not clear for me how it works actually. I've tried to remove the inheritance from the PageObject class and then it doesn't work and throws the NPE. 
Here is the part of my Page class:

```
public class PrototypePage extends PageObject {
private String userName = "//*[@id='x-auto-1-input']";
private String password = "//*[@id='x-auto-2-input']";
private String loginButton = "//*[@id='login_btn']";
private String usersDropDown = "//*[@id='x-auto-3-input']";
private String pid = "//*[@id='x-auto-4-input']";
private String pmid = "//*[@id='x-auto-5-input']";
private String fName = "//*[@id='x-auto-6-input']";
private String lName = "//*[@id='x-auto-7-input']";
private String address = "//*[@id='x-auto-8-input']";
private String city = "//*[@id='x-auto-10-input']";
private String state = "//*[@id='x-auto-11-input']";
private String zip = "//*[@id='x-auto-12-input']";
private String email = "//*[@id='x-auto-13-input']";
private String birthday = "//*[@id='x-auto-14-input']";
private String ssn = "//*[@id='x-auto-15-input']";
private String ssoServer = "//*[@id='x-auto-20-input']";
private String ssoRelayState = "//*[@id='x-auto-21-input']";
private String useIframe = "//label[contains(text(), 'Use iFrame:')]/following-sibling::div/div/div/div/div/label[contains(text(), '%s')]";
private String buttonSubmit = "//*[@id='submit_saml_btn']";

public WebElement findElementByXpath(String xpath) {
    return getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
}

public String getPmid()
{
    waitFor(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(pmid)));
    return findElementByXpath(pmid).getAttribute("value");
}
```

And here is my Steps class:

```
public class PrototypePageSteps {

PrototypePage prototypePage;

@Step
public void openPrototypePage() {
    prototypePage.getDriver().get("https://url.com/");
    prototypePage.getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
}

@Step
public void login(String uname, String pass) {
    prototypePage.login(uname, pass);
}

@Step
public void selectUserFromDropDown(String user) {
    prototypePage.selectUserFromDropDown(user);
}

@Step
public String getPmid() {
    return prototypePage.getPmid();
}
```

Actually, I want to know why does the `PrototypePage prototypePage;` object initialization works and nothing fails. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PrototypePage prototypePage;` is not object initialization (just declaration). Speculation, there is code in that package that sets the field. That is why the field has package private level access. See also the [Prototype Design Pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prototype-design-pattern/).

Comment: Maybe you are using a dependency injection framework. Are you using Spring by any chance?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, no, I don't use Spring. It's just a simple AT framework.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, now I got that this just a declaration but still don't understand how it works. Which code in that package that sets the field do you mean?

Comment: If there is an object being created without you explicitly creating it, then you *have* a dependency injection framework. The only question becomes "where is it being configured?"